# Подключить блог к сайту

Tags: wordpress

Мне нужно подключить блог к готовому сайту, проблема в том что мне не нужно что бы wordpress обрабатывал url которые я уже использую в проекте, например у меня есть поиск который я сам реализую, и соответсвенно что бы маршрут /search не обрабатывался бы wordpress'om.

Есть какие нибудь возможности сделать это, что бы не менять пол движка, и не так долго?

Comment: ваш вопрос не относится к программированию, перефразируйте вопрос

Comment: Просто создайте поддомен. Адрес будет например: blog.site.ru. У этого бога получиться отдельный движок.

Comment: Нет тут именно на этом же домене хотят сделать, поэтому наверное вариант с подпапкой подойдет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно разместить wordpress в подпапке, например `wordpress`. Из официального [кодекса](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC_WordPress_%D0%B2_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5):

1. Создайте новый каталог в который вы хотите поместить файлы WordPress (в примерах мы используем `/wordpress`).
2. Перейдите в панель Настройки.
3. В поле **Адрес WordPress (URL):** измените адрес на тот где будут размещены файлы WordPress. Например: http://example.com/wordpress
4. В поле **Адрес блога (URL):** измените адрес на URL корневого каталога. Например: http://example.com
5. Нажмите **Обновить настройки.** (Не расстраивайтесь из-за ошибок и не пытайтесь посмотреть ваш блог в этот момент!)
6. Переместите файлы WordPress в новый каталог (Адрес WordPress).
7. Скопируйте файлы index.php и .htaccess из каталога с WordPress в корневой каталог вашего сайта (Адрес блога).
8. Откройте файл index.php из корневого каталога в текстовом редакторе.
9. Внесите следующие изменения и сохраните файл. Измените строку, в которой написано:
   require('./wp-blog-header.php');
   на следующую, используя адрес каталога где размещен WordPress:
   require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
10. Войдите в новое место. Это может быть http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/
11. Если вы хотите настроить Постоянные ссылки, перейдите в Постоянные ссылки и обновите шаблон Постоянных ссылок. WordPress автоматически обновит ваш файл .htaccess если он имеет соответствующий файл. Если WordPress не сможет записать в ваш файл .htaccess, то он покажет вам записанное заново правило, чтобы вы сами вручную скопировали его в ваш файл .htaccess (в том же каталоге, где находится основной файл index.php.)